# Area of region under 2 curves.

Tags: calculus

Find the area of the region R enclosed by the line $y=2x−1$ and the parabola $y^2=4x+141$

Here is what I have done:

1. Write each equation in terms of x. ($x=\frac{y+1}{2}$ and $x=\frac{y^2-141}{4}$)
2. Find intersections: y= -11 and 13
3. Write the integral (I don't quite know).
4. Calculate answer.

If someone could check over my step 1 and 2 that would be awesome. Also If someone could do step 3 and 4 (would be awesome).

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct imo.

Comment: then just integrate $1/4(y^2 -2y -143)$ between $-11$ and $13$. Easy, it is a polynomial.

Comment: Do you know how to integrate?

Comment: @Arbuja Yes I do

Comment: Can you guys show me the work please? Yes its easy but I want to compare my work to yours. My answer to this question is -576, which doesn't seem right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked $1$ and $2$ and it is correct.

Step 3:

If $f(y)>g(y)$ for $x$-values between $[-11,13]$ then the integral is

$\int_{-11}^{13}{\left(f(y)-g(y)\right)}{dy}$

Since $\frac{y+1}{2}>\frac{y^2-141}{4}$ from $[-11,13]$ we have

$\int_{-11}^{13}\left(\frac{y+1}{2}-\frac{y^2-141}{4}\right)dy$

$\frac{1}{4}\int_{-11}^{13}\left({2y+2}-{y^2+141}\right)dy$

Now use the following rule that $\int{jy^k}dy=\frac{j}{k+1}y^{k+1}$

$\frac{1}{4}\int_{-11}^{13}\left(-y^2+2y+143\right)dy$

$\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_{-11}^{13}\left(-y^2\right)dy+\int_{-11}^{13}2ydy+\int_{-11}^{13}143dy\right)$

$\frac{1}{4}\left(\int_{-11}^{13}\left(-y^2\right)+\int_{-11}^{13}2y+\int_{-11}^{13}143\right)$

$\frac{1}{4}\left(|_{-11}^{13}\left(-\frac{1}{3}y^3\right)dy+|_{-11}^{13}{y^2}+|_{-11}^{13}143y\right)$

Now use $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)=F(b)-F(a)$ where $F(x)$ is the indefinite integral.

$\frac{1}{4}\left(\left(-\frac{1}{3}{(13)}^3+\frac{1}{3}{(-11)}^3\right)+\left({13}^{2}-(-11)^{2}\right)+\left(143(13)-143(-11)\right)\right)$

Now do the calculations on your calculator this ensure you did not make any mistakes.

$\frac{1}{4}(\frac{-2197-1331}{3}+48+3432)$

$\frac{1}{4}(\frac{-2197-1331+10440}{3})$

$\frac{6912}{12}=576$

You are correct.

Comment: The 4 outside the integral should be a 1/4?

Comment: I'll do the remaining steps to the answer of your answer for the area.

Comment: Right ∫f(x)= is F(b) - F(a)

Comment: my answer is 576